# Google Analytics traffic linked to wrong profile

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I've seen an unusual sudden drop in traffic to almost nothing - coinciding with some work I've had done to boost the loading page speed of my wordpress website.

This may or may not be relevant but new plugins were installed called 'WP Fastest Cache' and the premium version plus 'JCH Optimize Pro.'

I use Google Analytics by MonsterInsights to trace my traffic and the UA property in the plugin matches my UA property if I log into Google Analytics in a browser. I've not changed it and everything worked fine up until two days ago.

However, using 'Google Tag Manager' - it has identified the visits are being recorded but attributed to second UA profile that I didn't create and is not in my GA account!

Any ideas how I fix this?

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing the GA plugin but still all web visits are pointed at this other UA property.

The website address is: http://cricketyorkshire.com.

Thanks in advance for any help, John

Comment: You'll probably have to adjust the Tracking ID in your tags if there's a mismatch. From your site, your hits are going to UA-20331028-1.

Comment: @nyuen Thanks for the suggestion - I've implemented the tracking using the plugin...could you let me know how I would adjust the tracking ID in my tags? I wouldn't know how to begin to do that....

Any idea why traffic would randomly go to  UA-20331028-1 - I have no login  for this google account. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know much about WP plugins and how they implement GA/GTM, but for GTM, you would need to go directly into the tags and update the tracking ID there. Side note, if you're already tracking via GTM, then you should move away from having both GA (via plugin) and GTM. You get these kinds of issues if you're not careful. I would recommend sticking with GTM if you have some JS experience. It offers better control of what is tracked.